# Alternative for Router::requestAction in cakephp 2.x or calling controller action from route file

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

Router::requestAction has been removed in cakephp 2.x 
I need to call the action from route pages. Actually i want to update the cache for the url and from that i want to route the incoming pages. It was possible in 1.3 but no more used in higher version. How can i access the controller function when system checks on the route setting?

Comment: This sounds like you were doing something weird, and it broke. From the description, you shouldn't be calling `requestAction` - you should be calling whatever the controller action is calling.

Comment: @AD7six This could be really a bad practice or wrong logic. But i want to make something like this. Described in ADmad answer's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Router::requestAction()` never existed even in 1.3. The function you are referring to is probably `Object::requestAction()` and is available in 2.x also. But in 2.x `Router` doesn't extends `Object` anymore and hence the function is not available. Still I don't see why you need to call a controller action to update your url cache. I presume you have routes and/or url slugs stored in db which you need and for that you should have a model function which returns the required info.

Comment: My mistake its 1.2.5. 
My requirement
According to the url i need to route then to respective controller->action. I got problem that i can't fix the url route in the route.php file. 
Like 
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
Router::connect('/message/*', array('controller' => 'contacts', 'action' => 'sendmessage'));
Here pages and message they are fixed.

Comment: i'm saving this into the database. if i want to have 
 Router::connect('/xyz/*', array('controller' => 'contacts', 'action' => 'sendmessage'));
then i have write in route.php again. If i'am able to create cache then i can use it to route them. This could not be the right logic. But i need to have something like this.
Router::connect('/$abc/*', array('controller' =>$controller, 'action' => 'sendmessage'));
here $abc and $controller are defined in database.

Comment: So just as I mentioned initially there is no need to call a controller. Since the data you need comes from db all you need is access to model to get the info. You can use `$M = ClassRegistry::init('M')` to get the model instance and then do a find or call custom function.

Comment: Thank @Admad i got it. 
ClassRegistry::init('Model') i can use this according to my need. This solves my problem. Beside that i also don't need to create cache.